# How to compute $(X \cup Y)\setminus (X\cap \overline{Z})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show:
$(X \cup Y)\setminus (X\cap \overline{Z})$

Correct answer:[image: Correct answer]

I don't understand this.

Ok so  $(X \cup Y)$ are both X and Y.

$(X \cup Y)$$\setminus $ means all elements in A and B but not in $(X\cap \overline{Z})$

$\overline{Z} = Z^{C}$

Would not that imply that  $(X\cap \overline{Z})$ is just X?

Comment: I don't understand your final line... no $X\cap Z^c$ is not "just $X$"... it is the set of elements that are simultaneously in $X$ while also not being in $Z$.  Reworded, $X\cap Z^c$ is $X\setminus Z$.

Comment: Please avoid $\rm\LaTeX$-only titles.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz that makes things a lot easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X \cap \bar{Z}$ is the intersection of $X$ and the complement of $Z$, so it's all elements that are in $X$ and also in "not $Z$", i.e. it's the same as $X \setminus Z$.

So we want to find $(X \cup Y) \setminus (X \setminus Z)$, which is "everything that's in either $X$ or $Y$, but which isn't in ($X$ but not $Z$)".

Or, to look at it another way - draw your three-way Venn diagram, and let's name the segments so that $x = X \setminus (Y \cup Z)$, $xy = (X \cap Y) \setminus Z$, $xyz = X \cap Y \cap Z$ and so forth (i.e. $x$ is all the elements *only* in $X$, $xy$ is the elements in both $X$ and $Y$ but not $Z$, etc.)

Then $X \cup Y$ consists of $x$, $y$, $xy$, $xz$, $yz$ and $xyz$. $X \cap \bar{Z}$ consists of $x$, $y$, and $xy$. So the required set is all the parts in the first list that don't show up in the second list, which is $y$, $xz$, $yz$ and $xyz$ as the diagram shows.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take our set expression and re-express it in terms of the characteristic function of the sets.

$$ (X \cup Y) \setminus (X \cap \overline{Z}) \tag{Orig} $$

(Orig) becomes (101). In (101) we are interpreting $X, Y, Z$ as predicates that take an element in the domain of discourse and return true or false.

$$ (X \lor Y) \land \lnot (X \land \lnot Z) \tag{101} $$

Let's rewrite the expression in negative normal form:

$$ (X \lor Y) \land (\lnot X \lor Z) \tag{102} $$

Next, we distribute left and right.

$$ (X \land \lnot X) \lor (Y \land \lnot X) \lor (X \land Z) \lor (Y \land Z) \tag{103} $$

Remove expressions corresponding to false.

$$ (Y \land \lnot X) \lor (X \land Z) \lor (Y \land Z) \tag{104} $$

Let's examine all eight possibilities. This is exactly what we see in the diagram.

The `TruePreps` column tells us which prepositions are true for that row. The `Value` tells us whether the expression is true or false and `WinningDisjunct` is the disjunct in (104) that we're using the justify our claim that a particular row should be true.

```
TruePreps Value  WinningDisjunct (105)
None       0
X          0
Y          1     (Y and not X)
Z          0
XY         0
YZ         1     (Y and Z)
ZX         1     (X and Z)
XYZ        1     (Y and Z)
```